# Java find X % of a TreeMap

Tags: java

I have a `TreeMap` with Double Keys and String values for example:

```
TreeMap<Double,String> tm = new TreeMap<Double,String>();
tm.put(1,"worst");
tm.put(2,"middle");
tm.put(3,"best");
```

I need a way that I can get the X % of the treemap, so for example in this situation if I said:

get 33% then "best" would be returned and if I said 66% then "best" and middle would be returned.

Is there any easy way to do this? How can I iterate backwards through my map?

Comment: I don't think so with `TreeMap` because it's a map.  It's not really a searchable tree.  So to get your values you need to give the _exact_ key value, i.e. 1, 2, or 3.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can try something like this:

```
// ratio - 0.0 - 1.0
List<String> getRatio(Map<Double,String> map, double ratio)
{

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Entry<Double, String> e: map.entrySet()) {
        double newRatio = (double) result.size() / map.size();
        if (newRatio >= ratio)
            break;
        result.add(e.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: As I stated on the other answer, this is not an efficient way to find the closest match to a value.

Comment: @Jared you didn't understand question, OP is not searching for keys or values, just take first N elements (or first 33% of elements) of array/map/whatever

Comment: Then a TreeMap isn't the proper structure anyway.

Comment: @Jared why do you think so? do you know why OP has data in this structure, how this data used in other places of his/her app?